# Getting dyId: Symbol not found while checking the php version

Tags: php, homebrew

I brew installed the php@7.2 and now I restarted the php but I am not able to start the service. I tried checking php version using php -v and I am getting the following error:

```
php -v
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZNK6icu_698Calendar3getE19UCalendarDateFieldsR10UErrorCode
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34_4/bin/php
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib
 in /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34_4/bin/php
```

Can someone help me resolve this? I have spent numerous hours in this setup and installed and reinstalled php and everything still getting the same error. I tried cleaning everything up and doing the fresh installation but still I couldnot run it successfully.

Comment: 7.2 was end-of-lifed over a year ago, you shouldn't be starting a new install with anything less than 7.4.

Comment: Tried installing 7.4 as well still getting the same error: RohitsMac:php rohit.dubey$ brew services restart php@7.4
==> Successfully started `php@7.4` (label: homebrew.mxcl.php@7.4)
*****Mac:php $ php -v
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZNK6icu_698Calendar3getE19UCalendarDateFieldsR10UErrorCode
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34_4/bin/php
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib
 in /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34_4/bin/php
Abort trap: 6

Comment: try run `brew doctor` to see what is going on.

Comment: The error still shows `php@7.2` You probably didn't update your `PATH` with the new PHP version